# aws django file upload server responded with a status of 413

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i run a django application on aws Elastic Beanstalk with Python 3.7 and Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3.
My frontend is a vuejs javascript application.

I send a file (in my test with a size of 1,8 mb) to my django rest framework api. My javascript console shows:

[image]

With a lot of search and attempts i can't find a solution.

I use the following folder structure ([AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#awsui-expandable-section-69-trigger)) in my project to add config to nginx:

```
.platform
    -- nginx
        -- conf.d
            upload_size.config
            -- elasticbeanstalk
                upload_size.config
```

Content of the upload_size.config files:

```
client_max_body_size 25M;
```

But after i restart my elastic beanstalk and restart nginx again and again nothing changes...

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reason why it does not work, could be because you are using **wrong extention** for your config files.

For `nginx` they [should](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#awsui-expandable-section-69-trigger) be `*.conf`, not `*.config`.

There could be also issues with the config content itself, but the incorrect file extension is definitely one reason for the issues observed.